# Align tr the same way with unequal number of td

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I've got a problem with tr/td elements.

Here is what it looks like at the moment:
[image]

I want "Stromausfalltest 2017" to be aligned with the item underneath (as well the dot).

The problem is: the HTML is different.
As you can see the first item does not have a timespan, but the item above does.

That is the item I want to align:

```html
<tr class="fc-list-item ddk-fc-cs-0" target="_blank">
  <td class="fc-list-item-marker fc-widget-content">
    <span class="fc-event-dot"></span>
  </td>
  <td class="fc-list-item-title fc-widget-content">
    <a>Stromausfalltest 2017</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and that's the item underneath (with timespan):

```html
<tr class="fc-list-item ddk-fc-cs-0" target="_blank">
  <td class="fc-list-item-time fc-widget-content">11:30am - 12:30pm</td>
  <td class="fc-list-item-marker fc-widget-content">
    <span class="fc-event-dot"></span>
  </td>
  <td class="fc-list-item-title fc-widget-content">
    <a>1 x 10 + 4 x 20 + 1 x 25 Years DDK!</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that this HTML is rendered by a third-party API and I am not allowed to change the API.

Is there a solution with CSS?

Comment: where do you want to display the timespan instead? Or do you want to shift the first row more to the right?

Comment: @MatthiasS.  Yes, I want to shift the first row to the right so that it is aligned with the second one (although the first one does not have a timespan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a different in the classes on the rows that only have 2 tds in them then you could use a before rule in css to insert the extra td:

```
.ddk-fc-cs-0::before{
    content:" ";
    display:table-cell;
}
```

try adding that rule in. If the row with 2 td's always has the class .ddk-fc-cs-0 then that'll do the trick.

Here's a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/fsaud7e1/